# How can I using SQL Select in FoxPro add a non existing column with NULL?

Tags: sql, select, null, foxpro

Can I using SQL Select in FoxPro add a non existing column with NULL?

I have tried this select and it didn't work :-(

```
SELECT ID, .NULL. AS SomeColName FROM SomeDBF
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, TRANSFORM(.NULL.) AS SomeColName FROM SomeDBF
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're in VFP 9, it's better to use CAST() than TRANSFORM() because it allows you to specify the target data type. TRANSFORM() will always create a character field; looks like C(6). With CAST(), you specify:

```
SELECT CAST(.null. AS L) LogField, CAST(.null. AS N(8,3)) AS NumField, ;
       CAST(.null. AS C(10)) CharField ...
```

Comment: Good to know! Thank you very much!